# ¿Por qué no funciona mi ventana modal de bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Estoy trabajando con ASP.NET MVC 5 en un proyecto que requiere de una ventana modal para registrar a un nuevo usuario, el código es el siguiente:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Inicio de sesión</title>

  <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <form role="form">

          <div class="modal-header">
            <h2>Registro de usuarion</h2>

          </div>

          <br />
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="labels"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Nombre de usuario:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="labels"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Contraseña:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="password">
          </div>
          <br />
          <a href="#" class="btn" id="Registrar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>  Registrar</a>
          <div class="modal-footer">

          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myModal").modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Pero al ejecutarlo no me aparece nada, se supone que la ventana modal debe desplegarse sin necesidad de usar algún botón, pero la función de jQuery que lo hace parece no funcionar ¿Qué es lo que me falta agregarle?

Comment: Tu lo que quieres es que el modal se ejecute inmediatamente se cargue la página ?

Comment: @julian salas así es, también lo intente haciendo que se ejecute al pulsar un botón pero siguió sin funcionar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Carga Jquery antes que el archivo JS de Bootstrap.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>    
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con esta alternativa usando `dialog`.

```
 $("#myModal").dialog({
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    Ok: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  }
});
```

[Referencia](https://jqueryui.com/dialog)

Answer (score 0):

```
$().ready(function(){  
    $("#+id de tu modal").modal("show");  
});
```

verifica bien el id de tu modal
comprueba de que te este funcionando correctamente el jquery.js